# Why SO_RCVTIMEO timeout differs after it was set?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp

I am on Fedora 25. In the following test program I set recv timeout to 12 sec, 12345 microsec with `setsockopt`. But when I get timeout value with `getsockopt`, I get slightly different value: 12 sec, 13000 microsec. I expect it to be the same as it was set by `setsockopt`.

Why it differs ?

```
[ ~]$ cat sockopt.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

int main()
{
    int sd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    int rc;
    struct timeval tv;
    socklen_t len = sizeof(tv);

    tv.tv_sec = 12;
    tv.tv_usec = 12345;
    rc = setsockopt(sd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, &tv, sizeof(tv));
    if (rc < 0) printf("oops\n");

    rc = getsockopt(sd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, &tv, &len);
    if (rc < 0) printf("oops\n");
    printf("%ld, %ld\n",  tv.tv_sec, tv.tv_usec);
}
[ ~]$ 
[ ~]$ gcc -Wall sockopt.c
[ ~]$ 
[ ~]$ ./a.out 
12, 13000
[ ~]$
```

Comment: Perhaps the system doesn't have the resolution you ask for, and rounds up to the nearest microsecond possible?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: It's actually rounding to the nearest millisecond, question's mention of milliseconds is incorrect, `tv_usec` is measured in microseconds.

Comment: @BenVoigt, thanks, edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the kernel [sources](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/core/sock.c): when setting the `SO_RCVTIMEO` converts the `struct tv` into a `long` value, using arithmetic on the `HZ` value. On the other hand, when retrieving the `SO_RCVTIMEO` value, a `struct tv` is constructed from the `long` value. Hence, the result depends on the time resolution (the `HZ` value), and the arithmetic divisions and modulos.